# git branch -a does not show all remote branches

Tags: git, git-branch

My remote git server has 2 branches, develop and release.

I've cloned the repository, but when I do `git branch -a` I see:

```
* develop
  remotes/ghe/HEAD -> ghe/develop
  remotes/ghe/develop
```

I tried to do a `git fetch` but it did not update the list.

Comment: Try `git ls-remote` to see if it contains the `release` branch.

Comment: I found the issue. The repository was cloned with `--depth 1`. If I remove this flag it works. Expected behavior?

Comment: @NathanH Take a look at my answer.  Yes that is expected behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By running `git clone` with a `--depth` of 1, you're creating a **shallow clone**.  The behavior you saw is the default behavior *without* specifying `--no-single-branch` to get the tips of all branches, instead of the most recent single branch.  By not specifying this option, you're just getting the primary branch where the remote `HEAD` is pointing to.

If you wanted a shallow clone with the tips of *all branches* the solution would have been to specify the option `--no-single-branch`.

For more information, take a look at the [documentation on `git clone`.](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone)